# Struts2 theming freework or CSS

Tags: css, struts2

in mid level and higher level struts applications what is the method of arranging the form/webpage elements. Do we use use struts theming or do we stick on to our custom css like we do in other languages as Php. I'm a beginner so i find it difficult to arrange components in webpages with struts.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 supports themes for Forms. There exists some built in themes like simple, xhtml, css_xhtml. But it is really easy to create your own themes.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html

If you look for themes for your page layout you should search for css frameworks.
Take a look how it works in the [Struts2 jQuery Showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action). Try out the different Themes.